# Why Spring UriComponentsBuilder throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, spring

In order to have my Java SpringBoot application integrated with a regular REST endpoint, I have this method to prepare the URI

```
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

    private URI prepareEndpointUrl(MyQuery q) {
    return UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(apiConfiguration.getLeadTimesPreCalcRestEndpointUrl())
            .queryParam(PARAM1, q.getCountryFrom())
            .queryParam(PARAM2, q.getZipCodeFrom())
            .queryParam(PARAM3, q.getCountryTo())
            .queryParam(PARAM4, q.getZipCodeTo())
            .build().toUri();
}
```

The URL is being passed by parameter to UriComponentsBuilder as a first argument depends on which environment my application is running.

Works perfectly for all lower environments, but in prod is throwing a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

```
ERROR @ o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] | Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [ https://A_VALID_HOST/api/XX-YY.json] is not a valid HTTP URL] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [ https://A_VALID_HOST/api/XX-YY.json] is not a valid HTTP URL
```

I google this, and apparently it could be related with encoding the url/parameters, whch I am not doing. Apparentrly something is different in this env, and I have not idea how to start finding what.

any idea?

Comment: Is there really a space between `[` and `h`?

Comment: `https://A_VALID_HOST/api/XX-YY.json` - are you expecting a placeholder in place of `A_VALID_HOST`?

Comment: Hi @StephenC, yes, that was the error. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

As marked by Stephen above, the problem was a blank space in my URL, before *http*.

Apparently, is not trimmed; thanks everyone.